# Added chapter with \addcontentsline does not appear on ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I add four chapters with `\addcontentsline` after `\bibliography`, however, there are only three chapters appearing in the Table of Contents. Could you please tell me what I should do?

Sorry for my unspecification. I use `\documentclass{book}`, and I typed that :

```
\bibliography{refs.bib}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

%%%%%%%%%%%

\include{Appendix 1}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix 1}

\thispagestyle{empty}

%%%%%%%%%%%%

\include{Appendix 2}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix 2}

\thispagestyle{empty}

%%%%%%%%%%%%

\include{Appendix 3}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix 3}

\thispagestyle{empty}

%%%%%%%%%%%%

\include{Appendix 4}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix 4}

\thispagestyle{empty}
```

But then it appears only 3 first appendices.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) So stated the problem is not very clear. What class are you using? Can you give an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`\addcontentsline` is written to the toc when the page is "shipped out". If the command is on an empty page which is not written to the pdf or dvi it gets lost - it wouldn't have much sense anyway as without page there is no sensible page number.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

blub 
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{section 1}
\newpage
%empty page 
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{section 2} %lost
\end{document}
```

Comment: I start to understand how you think your answers out while shopping! +1 :)